# collisionBitMask values not working in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have two entities that I want to collide with each other. I have a struct to keep track of the different physics categories:

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let Player: Int32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let Obstacle: Int32 = 0x1 << 2
    static let Ground: Int32 = 0x1 << 3
}
```

I want my Player node to collide with my Obstacle nodes. Here are my Player node's physics:

```
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: (self.size))
    self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Player)
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Obstacle)
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Ground)
```

Here are my Obstacle node's physics

```
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: self.size)
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Obstacle)
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Player)
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Ground)
    self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    self.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: -240, dy: 0)
    self.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    self.physicsBody?.friction = 0
```

When they cross paths, they just pass through each other. However, they both collide with the Ground properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The basic of the programmation tell that if you write x = 1 and after x = 2, your x is 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `collisionBitMask` when you set it up for the second time. You should set up an `OR` bitmask with the symbol `|`.

Replace

```
self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Obstacle)
self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Ground)
```

with:

```
self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Obstacle) | UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Ground)
```

and

```
self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Player)
self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Ground)
```

with:

```
self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Player) | UInt32(PhysicsCategory.Ground)
```